# Каков минимальный набор девайсов для тестирования мобильных приложений (iOS+Android)?

Tags: android, ios, мобильная-разработка

Каков минимальный набор девайсов для тестирования мобильных приложений (iOS+Android)?

Comment: 0. Достаточно эмулятора. А вообще конкретного числа нет. Всё зависит от того какие фичи и как подробно надо тестировать.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от задачи которую вы перед собой ставите. Если Вы не будете использовать какую то экзотику то достаточно одного телефона (только не noname и со стоковой прошивкой - это касается Android), и планшета - если вы предполагаете что Ваша программа будет работать на нем в том числе. 
Что касается разных версий - то эмулятора хватит за глаза.

PS
Обратите внимание что для IOS можно программировать только на технике Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Для тестирования UI достаточно нескольких устройств с разнотипной диагональю. А вот прогонять юнит тесты, интеграционные тесты и пр. лучше на устройствах разных производителей и с разными версиями операционной системы.

Например, если говорить об Android - то на устройствах от Samsung есть проблемы при работе с Context, которых нет на устройствах других производителей.

Если говорить про iOS, то некоторые платформенные функции на разных устройствах при равной версии iOS могут выполнятся по разному.

Имхо, самый удобный вариант это использование CI (continuous integration). Девелоперское тестирование производится на симуляторах и / или устройствах доступных под рукой, а прогон всех тестов производится с помощью одной "жирной" билд конфигурации на CI сервере, и на разных версиях систем + разных устройствах.